# "adb switch-user" often freezes android phone

Tags: android, adb, multi-user

When I do from adb `am switch-user 10` (user 10 or any user), my Moto X Play with Android 5.1.1 crashes and I have to restart it. It is not exactly a freeze because I can see notification poping in the background. But the "Switching to ..." stays eternaly on the middle of the screen.

How to fix this ? I need multiple users, so it's very annoying.
Thank you

Comment: any log from the crash?

Comment: @Lino how can I get these logs from adb ?

Comment: Hi Chaussette! Please edit your question after familiarising yourself with https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as it will help improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @Chaussette you can try with `adb locat`